With Tom-Select, how do I place the selected item at the top or in the middle of the drop-down list?
In a symfony form I have a select with the autocomplete option to activate tom-select.
When I select an item and display the select again, the selected item is displayed as the last item in the visible list.
I'd like to move it up a few positions before displaying it.
With Tom-Select, how do I place the selected item at the top or in the middle of the drop-down list?

Problem solved : Thanks to chatGPT and the Symfony Documentation.
(symfony.com/bundles/ux-autocmplete/current/index.html#extending-tom-select)
event.detail.options.onDropdownOpen = (dropdown) => {
    var scrollableElement = dropdown.querySelector('.ts-dropdown-content');
    var selectedOption = scrollableElement.querySelector('.selected');
    if (selectedOption) {
        var dropdownHeight = scrollableElement.clientHeight;
        var selectedOptionHeight = selectedOption.clientHeight;
        var visiblePartHeight = dropdownHeight / 2;
        var selectedOptionTop = selectedOption.offsetTop;
        var scrollPosition = selectedOptionTop - visiblePartHeight + (selectedOptionHeight / 2);
        setTimeout(function() {
            scrollableElement.scrollTop = scrollPosition;
        }, 50);
    }
};

